Unable to Import JoditEditor in .tsx file
I've imported the jodit-react project using
yarn add jodit-react
yarn install

now I'm trying to import it into a file
import React, { ReactElement, useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { useController } from 'react-hook-form';
import ModalWrapper from '../../shared/modals/ModalWrapper';
import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";


interface ControlledWysiwygWithLabelProps {
  id: string;
  labelClass?: string;
  labelText?: string;
  sublabelHtml?: string;
  init?: any;
  formInputName: string;
  formControl: any;
  defaultValue: any;
  inputRef?: any;
  onClick?: () => void;
  onFocus?: () => void;
  onBlur?: (e: unknown) => void
}

const ControlledWysiwygWithLabel = ({
  id,
  labelClass = 'block text-sm font-medium text-gray-700',
  labelText,
  sublabelHtml,
  init = {},
  formInputName,
  formControl,
  defaultValue,
  inputRef,
  onClick,
  onFocus,
  onBlur,
}: ControlledWysiwygWithLabelProps): ReactElement => {
  const { field: { onChange, value } } = useController({
    name: formInputName,
    control: formControl,
    defaultValue,
  });

  const editor = useRef(null);

  const config = {
    readonly: false
  }

  const handleEditorChange = (newValue: string) => {
    onChange(newValue);
    if (inputRef && typeof inputRef.current !== 'undefined' && inputRef.current !== null) {
      inputRef.current.value = newValue;
    }
  };

  // const [isFullScreen, setIsFullScreen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      {labelText && (
        <>
          <label htmlFor={formInputName} className={labelClass}>
            {labelText}
          </label>
        </>
      )}
      {sublabelHtml && (
        <div className="py-2 text-xs italic text-gray-500">
          {sublabelHtml}
        </div>
      )}
      <div className="mt-1">
        <JoditEditor
          ref={editor}
          value={value}
          config={config}
          onBlur={handleEditorChange}
          onChange={handleEditorChange}
        />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default ControlledWysiwygWithLabel;

When I run my webpack server I am met with the following import errors:
ERROR in ./app/javascript/components/application/halda-design-system/inputs/ControlledWysiwygWithLabel.tsx 86:38-48
"export 'default' (imported as 'JoditReact') was not found in 'jodit-react'
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency._getErrors (/Users/jonny/ws/round-robin/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:109:11)
    at HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.getErrors (/Users/jonny/ws/round-robin/node_modules/webpack/lib/dependencies/HarmonyImportSpecifierDependency.js:68:16)
    at Compilation.reportDependencyErrorsAndWarnings (/Users/jonny/ws/round-robin/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1463:22)
    at /Users/jonny/ws/round-robin/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1258:10
    at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/Users/jonny/ws/round-robin/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:15:1)
    at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (/Users/jonny/ws/round-robin/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:154:20)
    at Compilation.finish (/Users/jonny/ws/round-robin/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:1253:28)
    at /Users/jonny/ws/round-robin/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:672:17
    at _done (eval at create (/Users/jonny/ws/round-robin/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:9:1)
    at eval (eval at create (/Users/jonny/ws/round-robin/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:80:22)

Here's the contents of my yarn.lock
jodit-react@^4.1.2:
  version "4.1.2"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/jodit-react/-/jodit-react-4.1.2.tgz#61ef1d6fa1f37cde7b71f666da8be9f6fb70f913"
  integrity sha512-Hs1evpM1IK5zvy/5m5Gk819L8aC+9EmEdQvCoLHVUr/R3vtH4nYFD6wsMRj3ur3J4ZHhaSBjt0N3R7ggwP405Q==
  dependencies:
    jodit "^4.2.10"

jodit@^4.2.10:
  version "4.2.10"
  resolved "https://registry.yarnpkg.com/jodit/-/jodit-4.2.10.tgz#5d8082d3d9566711353c60cb815ce5598c4dc9a8"
  integrity sha512-Jj+8/tUXg77zhoKAAe4Reub5RsMkMSTkxLNL4l2rvQcneWyHzO0uoGFZZ1Rx4jWlKEQHwBSw3E7JZ93DZ/VOVA==
  dependencies:
    autobind-decorator "^2.4.0"

Here's the index.d.ts of my jodit-react
import { Jodit } from 'jodit/esm/index';
import * as React from 'react';

type DeepPartial<T> = T extends object
    ? {
            [P in keyof T]?: DeepPartial<T[P]>;
      }
    : T;

export interface IJoditEditorProps {
    value: string;

    className?: string;

    config?: DeepPartial<Jodit['options']>;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    onChange?: (newValue: string) => void;
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    onBlur?: (newValue: string) => void;
}

declare const JoditEditor: React.ForwardRefExoticComponent<
    React.PropsWithoutRef<IJoditEditorProps> & React.RefAttributes<Jodit>
>;

export default JoditEditor;
export { Jodit };

I've attempted nuking my node modules and reinstalling.
